# Setting a PHP $_SESSION['username'] using a jQuery $.post call and a callback method

Tags: php, jquery, session, post, callback

I've researched and played around a fair bit, but I am stumped. Essentially I want to setup my site so that it can detect if a user is 'logged in' and thereby change the way it looks: removing the "Sign In" link and replacing it with a "Sign Out" link, and so forth.

For testing purposes I started my index.html page with:

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
$_SESSION["username"]="javaman";
?>
```

Next, I call my setup function from within the jquery document.ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setup_page();
};
```

The setup function looks like:

```
function setup_page()
{
    var username = get_user();

    //check for error
    var index = username.indexOf("error");

    //if not an error
    if(username.length > 0 && index == -1)
    {
        //do the jquery calls to hide/show links
    }
}
```

And that get_user function looks like:

```
function get_user()
{
    var result;

    $.post("./session.php", {action : "get", key : "username", value : "val"}, function(data){
            result = data;

        });

    return result;
}
```

The session.php is a simple app that takes in 3 post values and hopefully spits out the proper result, the problem I am running into is that the js result variable is often undefined, especially so when I debug via the IE dev toolbar. FF seems ok though. Am I using the callback in the correct way? I've tried putting alert() functions everywhere to figure out where the code is screwing up, but that doesn't help either as often the alert's say the result is undefined. Meanwhile, it seems like the get_user calls the post function but the stack immediately returns and never gets to the return statement until AFTER the get_user has returned a value of.. undefined. I believe I am misunderstanding the code flow here. I am used to C where logically one function follows another. In that vein I am interpreting the callback to essentially be like:

int i = callback_function(post("some data"));

So in my mind the post completes it's action and then calls another function or at least performs another action and then that completes and then the get_user can return it's value.

Or is the order of operation: post, get_user, callback?

...confused in Seattle

Comment: i wouldn't use the js al all, as its not secure, check the session with php, and build the page appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet Explorer does not natively support `indexOf` on arrays. Use jQuery's `$.inArray()` instead:

```
var index = $.inArray("error", username);
```

Comment: Ahh, thanks! Is there a resource which specifies what IE does and does not support? Or does jQuery have docs on what functions to use to support as many browsers as possible?

Comment: There are a lot of resources out there. Can't think of anything specific at the moment. P.S. If my answer solved your problem, then accept it as the correct answer - by clicking on the check mark to the left of my answer - so that other people coming to this post will know that this is the correct answer.

Comment: @Steve indexOf function is a native javascript function got nothing to do with jquery . Stupid IE fault entirely .

Comment: Roger that, what's the best way to make sure to use the right function? Is there some if statement I can include in my code where if the browser is IE I will use inArray() and else I can use indexOf?

Comment: `$.inArray()` will work perfectly fine in all other browsers as well. No need to pollute your code with unnecessary conditional statements.

Comment: unless I am doing it wrong, but var index = jQuery.indexOf("error",data); always returns -1 for me. However when I use this bit: http://stellapower.net/content/javascript-support-and-arrayindexof-ie it works in IE

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that AJAX stands for **Asynchronous** Javascript and XML. So the callback fires as soon as a response comes, but the rest of execution goes on. If you want to lock the execution until AJAX-request will be completed, use

```
$.ajaxSetup({async:false});
```

before AJAX call.

Comment: So whenever I want the site to wait until the ajax completes, I need to use ajaxSetup? If I use it, will I have to $.ajaxSetup({async:true}); immediately afterward?

Comment: Either that or use $.ajax() with **async** option.

Comment: Though $.post() is a shorthand method for $.ajax(), so you can try adding `async:false` option to your `post` call, it may work too.